# How to concrete a string with GetWindowsDirectoryA returned result?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm using this `GetWindowsDirectoryA` Windows API function to get the location for Windows folder.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#ifdef __WIN32
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <sysinfoapi.h>
#endif

std::string GetOSFolder() {
        std::vector<char> buffer(MAX_PATH + 1);

        GetWindowsDirectoryA(buffer.data(), MAX_PATH);

        std::string windowsRoot{ buffer.data(), buffer.size() };

        return windowsRoot + "/SomeFolder";
}

int main() {
    std::cout << GetOSFolder() << "\n";
}
```

I want to concrete a folder name with the returned Windows folder string result.

```
windowsRoot + "/SomeFolder"
```

Above attempt results the following string,

```
C:\Windows

                                   /SomeFolder
```

This seems happening because the buffer size is set to `MAX_PATH` which is larger than the actual string.

Is there a way to construct the string from buffer with actual string size?

Comment: Please read the [`GetWindowsDirectoryA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getwindowsdirectorya) documentation. Especially what it *returns*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could initialize the string with the path, you wouldn't even need to know the size (which is returned by `GetWindowsDirectoryA` as stated in the comment section), but it's advisable to use it given that it does optimize `std::string` initialization.

Example:

```
std::string GetOSFolder() {

    char buffer[MAX_PATH + 1];
   const auto size = GetWindowsDirectoryA(buffer, MAX_PATH);
    if (size) {
        return std::string(buffer, size).append("/SomeFolder");
    }
    return ""; // or however you want to handle the error
}

int main() {

    std::cout << GetOSFolder() << "\n";
}
```

Or you could avoid the second variable for buffer but you then have to resize the original buffer:

```
std::string GetOSFolder() {

    std::string buffer(MAX_PATH + 1, 0);
    auto result = GetWindowsDirectoryA(buffer.data(), MAX_PATH); // or &buffer[0] prior to C++17
    if (result) {
        buffer.resize(result);
        return buffer.append("/SomeFolder");
    }
    return buffer; // will be an empty string if API call fails
}
```

Now, if you want to avoid resize you could still use some trickery:

```
std::string GetOSFolder() {

    const auto size = GetWindowsDirectoryA(nullptr , 0);
    if (size) {
        std::string buffer(size, 0);
        const auto result = GetWindowsDirectoryA(buffer.data(), MAX_PATH); // or &buffer[0] prior to C++17
        if (result) {
            return buffer.append("\\OtherPath");
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Here you call `GetWindowsDirectoryA` twice, the first  one to know the size you need for your buffer, the second to actually retrieve the path.

Note that in this last option, the first call will return the length of the string with the null terminator whereas the second call will only return the length of the string without including the null byte as is typical in WIN32 API for this type of call, it's a well-known pattern.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234559/discussion-on-answer-by-anastaciu-how-to-concrete-a-string-with-getwindowsdirect). Please make sure to incorporate all feedback into the answer by [edit]ing it.